# Sharing a configuration between java client and server applications

Tags: java, client-server, data-sharing

I'm building a java client server application (both are JSE), here a quick description.

- **Server**
  The server interact with an external system receiving "requests" and providing "responses" to these requests via TCP/IP.
  The content of the "response" depends on "rules" described into a "rules deposit".
- **Client**
  Clients are Java applications connected via HornetMQ to server.
  I have multiple clients that (not simultaneously) can change the "rules deposit" to update/change or correct the response behavior.

My question is: how I implement this shared "rules deposit"? Are common frameworks I can use ?

Some notes:
I cannot use shared file
I'm not obliged to use HornetMQ
I prefer not to use Database RDBMS

Comment: Clients should access the "rules-deposit" through calls to the server, i.e. the server should offer an API to access the rules-deposit. Then on th server, store in in whatever technology you like (why not RDBMS ?)

Comment: If possible I prefer not to implement a specific protocol for my needs. I prefer not to use DB because I'm not sure I can access DB directly from clients.